# Foreign keys, more hindrance then helpful?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I used mysql workbench to design a database. I used the tool to make pretty lines between tables, this automatically added in a foreign key for me.

Here are my 2 create statements:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`PROFILE` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `some_int` BIGINT NULL COMMENT 'an int',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`USER_ACCOUNT` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field1` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `field2` CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `PROFILE_user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_address_UNIQUE` (`email_address` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_USER_ACCOUNT_PROFILE1_idx` (`PROFILE_user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_USER_ACCOUNT_PROFILE1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PROFILE_user_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`PROFILE` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I can't insert into one without running into things like `ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` - I tried inserting into the child first, but doesn't seem to make a difference.

I then figured that, since I drew a 1:1 relationship, the key must mean for every entry in PROFILE I have a entry in USER_ACCOUNT - otherwise what is the point of the foreign key? Using this idea I inserted into the child first, then wrote an update query for the parent using the same user_id, the update didn't work.

So my first question, what is the point of this foreign key? I know there is a 1:1 relationship between the table so should I enforce it?

Secondly, how do I insert into this?  My own foreign keys aren't letting me insert data.

Thanks, any help would be great I am a little rusty at DB design.

Comment: Just to complete the picture: other DBMS that have better support for foreign keys would actually let you solve this problem by using a deferrable foreign key. But I agree with Arth that you probably created the FK constraint with the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you don't need a `UNIQUE` index on the `PRIMARY KEY` the `PRIMARY KEY` already enforces that.

Secondly, conceptually you have added the foreign key to the wrong table, as a profile should reference a user.. this is probably where your problems are coming from.

I'd suggest the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`USER_ACCOUNT` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field1` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `field2` CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_address_UNIQUE` (`email_address` ASC)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`PROFILE` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `some_int` BIGINT NULL COMMENT 'an int',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PROFILE_USER_ACCOUNT1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`USER_ACCOUNT` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And insert your users into `USER_ACCOUNT` and then `PROFILE`.

Q. Should I enforce the foreign key?

A. Almost certainly, it prevents your data from getting in an inconsistent state. Profiles could be added that have a deleted user or a user that does not exist. Knowing that your data is always consistent makes querying, displaying data and debugging a lot easier as there is less to worry about.